# UserControl IsEnabled property value set by ValueConverter ignored

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, ivalueconverter

This is inside an MVVM project. I have a WPF `UserControl` within another `UserControl`, like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.ParentUserControl" ...>
    <local:ChildUserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}" IsEnabled="{Binding ChildViewModel, Converter={StaticResource n2bf}}" />
</UserControl>
```

My `n2bf` resource is my `NullToBooleanConverter` which returns `False` if the `Convert` method's `value` is `null`. Debugging shows the converter is working correctly.

However when I run my program the `ChildUserControl` instance is enabled. I used the Snoop tool and to my surprise it shows the `IsEnabled` property is locally set to `True`!

I changed my `Convert` method to return `false` under all circumstances however the UserControl is still enabled at runtime. However when I change my XAML to this it works fine:

```
<local:ChildUserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}" IsEnabled="False" />
```

So why is the `False` value from my Converter being ignored and the `IsEnabled` property set to `True`?

Comment: You might want to add some more code to check. The last line of code has nothing to do with binding or the converter so basically it should work unless it has been changed behind the scenes.

Comment: The DataContext and IsEnabled Bindings look inconsistent. Have you tried 'IsEnabled="{Binding Converter={StaticResource n2bf}}"'?

Comment: The most obvious reason I can think of for why this happens is your ChildViewModel binding is simply failing. If it fails, I'm pretty sure the default value defaults to something and I'm thinking that something defaults to true. Have you checked that it is definitely binding? That or perhaps ChildViewModel really isn't null when you think it is.